# Take data from List on equal parts (samples) C#

Tags: c#, list, slice

Consider I have the following List:

```
var numbers = new List<int>(){ 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 4 };
```

and I have a variable that contains the number of samples that I want to take from the array:

```
const int SAMPLES_COUNT = 4;
```

My goal is to take 4 samples on equal ranges ( as much as possible ) from the list and put them into another list. For example the new list should look like this:

```
var samples = new List<int>(){ 3, 7, 9, 4};
```

Is there any work around in order to achieve this result.

Comment: What would be the expected output if the list didn't have the 4 at the end?  Would it just take 1?  What if it didn't have the 1 or the 4?

Comment: If you know the `SAMPLES_COUNT` and the count of elements in `numbers`, would you always take every nth element?

Comment: The  numbers.Count is always greater than SAMPLES_COUNT

Comment: @juharr The expected output would be 3, 7, 8, 1

Comment: @gunr2171 Mistake, it's the other way around.

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by a sample nor what "take 4 samples on equal ranges ( as much as possible )" means. You should definitly provide some examples of your data and what you expect the code to do in those cases.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I provided examples, Is there anything that you are unfamiliar with.

Comment: What would be the expected output of `{ 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 4, 5 }`? `{ 3, 7, 1, 5 }`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use arithmetic to get the mod number and use loop or lambda to make it.

```
const int SAMPLES_COUNT = 4;
var numbers = new List<int>(){ 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 4 };
var divNumber = Math.Ceiling((decimal)numbers.Count / (decimal)SAMPLES_COUNT);
var result = numbers.Where((x,i)=> i % divNumber == 0).ToList();
```